# SQL - Finding/Matching "pairs" in the same table, by event/date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having issues developing a working solution/query for the case I bring you.

I have a table that receives agent data. What I need is a way to find out the matching "pairs", by day and event, in order to insert them in a temp table, so they can be worked. There can be several entries/pairs in the same day.

A sample of what i'm talking about:

| Event Date | AGENT | Event Type | Event Subtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 09:00 | AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL | LOGIN |
| 2022-03-14 11:10 | AGENT 1 | BREAK | START |
| 2022-03-14 11:20 | AGENT 1 | BREAK | END |
| 2022-03-14 13:10 | AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL | LOGOUT |
| 2022-03-14 14:00 | AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL | LOGIN |
| 2022-03-14 15:50 | AGENT 1 | BREAK | START |
| 2022-03-14 16:00 | AGENT 1 | BREAK | END |
| 2022-03-14 18:10 | AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL | LOGOUT |
| 2022-03-14 10:00 | AGENT 2 | TICKET CHANNEL | LOGIN |
| 2022-03-14 12:00 | AGENT 2 | BREAK | START |
| 2022-03-14 12:10 | AGENT 2 | BREAK | END |
| 2022-03-14 14:00 | AGENT 2 | TICKET CHANNEL | LOGOUT |

In this case the 1st agent 1 'voice channel'+'login' should be paired with the first agent 1 'voice channel'+'logout', the first 'break'+'start' should be paired with the first 'break'+'end', the second agent 1 'voice channel'+'login' with the second agent 1 'voice channel'+'logout' and the second 'break'+'start' with the second 'break'+'end', and so forth.

The destination temp table will have the columns 'Agent', 'event', 'event start' and 'event end'.

@Coder1991 The final temp table should read something like this:

| AGENT | Event Type | Event Start | Event End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL | 2022-03-14 09:00 | 2022-03-14 13:00 |
| AGENT 1 | BREAK | 2022-03-14 11:10 | 2022-03-14 11:20 |
| AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL | 2022-03-14 14:00 | 2022-03-14 18:00 |
| AGENT 1 | BREAK | 2022-03-14 15:50 | 2022-03-14 16:00 |
| AGENT 2 | TICKET CHANNEL | 2022-03-14 10:00 | 2022-03-14 14:00 |
| AGENT 2 | BREAK | 2022-03-14 12:00 | 2022-03-14 12:10 |

Any suggestions / inputs are appreciated.

Thank you all in advance, and have a great week.

Comment: can you show us the expected sample output?

Comment: Would `order by agent,[event date],[event type],[event subtype]` not give you this?  You could add a table of rankings, so login is 1 and logout is 2 and use a join to this to order them as desired

Comment: `2022-03-14 13:00` doesn't exist in the source data

Comment: Is there any possibility that the communications overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Gaps-And-Islands trick for this.

A ranking can be calculated via using a `SUM OVER` a flag.
And the flag is the start of the types per agent.

Once you have the rank, it just a matter of aggregation.

> ```
> SELECT AGENT, [Event Type]
> , MIN(CASE WHEN [Event SubType] IN ('LOGIN', 'START') THEN [Event Date] END) AS [Event Start] 
> , MAX(CASE WHEN [Event SubType] IN ('LOGOUT', 'END')  THEN [Event Date] END) AS [Event End] 
> FROM
> (
> SELECT [Event Date], AGENT, [Event Type], [Event Subtype]
> , Rnk = SUM(IIF([Event SubType] IN ('LOGIN', 'START'), 1, 0)) 
>         OVER (PARTITION BY AGENT, [Event Type], CAST([Event Date] AS DATE) ORDER BY [Event DATE])
> FROM agent_events 
> ) q
> GROUP BY AGENT, [Event Type], CAST([Event Date] AS DATE), Rnk
> ORDER BY AGENT, [Event Start];
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> AGENT   | Event Type     | Event Start      | Event End       
> :------ | :------------- | :--------------- | :---------------
> AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL  | 2022-03-14 09:00 | 2022-03-14 13:10
> AGENT 1 | BREAK          | 2022-03-14 11:10 | 2022-03-14 11:20
> AGENT 1 | VOICE CHANNEL  | 2022-03-14 14:00 | 2022-03-14 18:10
> AGENT 1 | BREAK          | 2022-03-14 15:50 | 2022-03-14 16:00
> AGENT 2 | TICKET CHANNEL | 2022-03-14 10:00 | 2022-03-14 14:00
> AGENT 2 | BREAK          | 2022-03-14 12:00 | 2022-03-14 12:10
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=de1bb6af1a17b8711dc7bc493aab9bac)*

Comment: This is the right direction indeed. I discovered some issues using this method, but data related and not with the query per se (things like not having pairs and such). Thanks for the suggestion, LukStorms, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below approach

```
 declare @tbl table([Event Date] datetime,AGENT varchar(10),[Event Type] 
 varchar(20)
,[Event Subtype] varchar(20)
 )

insert into @tbl
values('2022-03-14 09:00','AGENT 1','VOICE CHANNEL','LOGIN')
,('2022-03-14 11:10','AGENT 1','BREAK','START')
,('2022-03-14 11:20','AGENT 1','BREAK','END')
,('2022-03-14 13:10','AGENT 1','VOICE CHANNEL','LOGOUT')
,('2022-03-14 14:00','AGENT 1','VOICE CHANNEL','LOGIN')
,('2022-03-14 15:50','AGENT 1','BREAK','START')
,('2022-03-14 16:00','AGENT 1','BREAK','END')
,('2022-03-14 18:10','AGENT 1','VOICE CHANNEL','LOGOUT')
,('2022-03-14 19:00','AGENT 1','VOICE CHANNEL','LOGIN')
,('2022-03-14 20:10','AGENT 1','VOICE CHANNEL','LOGOUT')
,('2022-03-14 10:00','AGENT 2','TICKET CHANNEL','LOGIN')
,('2022-03-14 12:00','AGENT 2','BREAK','START')
,('2022-03-14 12:10','AGENT 2','BREAK','END')
,('2022-03-14 14:00','AGENT 2','TICKET CHANNEL','LOGOUT')


select *
, case when ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by agent,[Event Type] order by [Event Date]) % 2
 != 0 then [Event Date] else null end 
[Event Start]
,case when ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by agent,[Event Type] order by [Event Date]) % 2
 = 0 then [Event Date] else null end 
[Event End]
into #temp
from @tbl

;with cte as(
select AGENT,[Event Type],[Event Start]
,lead([Event End],1)over(partition by agent,[Event Type] order by [Event Date]) [Event End]
from
#temp
)
select *
from cte 
where [Event Start] is not null
order by AGENT,[Event Start] 

drop table #temp
```